# Condicional case con select - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Con ayuda de esta comunidad, he podido ir avanzando bastante con una query que necesito. Ahora tengo un detalle, lo comento.
Tengo esta query, que genera total general, total segun un rango de fecha y la diferencia del total general entre meses (Mes 6 - Mes 5, Mes 5 - Mes 4... etc).

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Fecha_factura) as Anio,
    MONTH(Fecha_factura) as Mes,
    FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) as Total_general,
    FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(Fecha_Factura) < DAY(GETDATE()) THEN Venta_neta ELSE 0 END)) AS Total_al_dia,
    FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) - LEAD(FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta))) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura) DESC, MONTH(Fecha_factura) DESC) AS Diferencia,
FROM Ventas
WHERE Fecha_Factura >= '20190501'
    AND LEFT(Codigo_departamento,2) IN ('F3','N1','N3','R1','R3','S1','T1','T3')
GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha_factura), MONTH(Fecha_factura)
ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura) DESC, MONTH(Fecha_factura) DESC
```

El asunto es que me plantearon un nuevo pedido y tengo la query que lo genera:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Fecha_factura) as Anio,
    MONTH(Fecha_factura) as Mes,
    FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) as Total_fecha_cierre
FROM Ventas
WHERE
    Fecha_factura IN (
        SELECT Fecha
        FROM fecha_cierre
    )
    AND LEFT(Codigo_departamento,2) IN ('F3','N1','N3','R1','R3','S1','T1','T3')
GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha_factura), MONTH(Fecha_factura)
ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura) DESC, MONTH(Fecha_factura) DESC
```

Como pueden ver, las queries son "identicas", pero cambia el la condicional del `where`, el cual busca el match en otra tabla llamada `fecha_cierre`. Entonces, mi idea es poder generar solo una query, la cual use la primera que mostre, y agregue `Total_fecha_cierre` a mi consulta.

Trate utilizando el ejemplo de CASE, pero no me funciono:

```
FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN Fecha_factura IN (SELECT Fecha FROM fecha_cierre) THEN Venta_neta ELSE 0 END))
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es vincular con la tabla que tiene las fechas (LEFT JOIN utilizando las fechas para vincular), y luego utilizar un CASE en el SELECT: si la fecha en la tabla vinculada (fecha_cierre o de_rpa_gaxu_fecha_cierre, no se cual de los dos es el nombre de la tabla) no es nula (hubo match) sumas el valor de la venta neta, sino cero.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Fecha_factura) as Anio,
    MONTH(Fecha_factura) as Mes,
    FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) as Total_general,
    FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(Fecha_Factura) < DAY(GETDATE()) THEN Venta_neta ELSE 0 END)) AS Total_al_dia,
    FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta)) - LEAD(FLOOR(SUM(Venta_neta))) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura) DESC, MONTH(Fecha_factura) DESC) AS Diferencia,
    FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN fecha_cierre.Fecha IS NOT NULL THEN Venta_neta ELSE 0 END)) as Total_fecha_cierre

FROM Ventas
LEFT JOIN fecha_cierre ON Ventas.Fecha_factura = fecha_cierre.Fecha
WHERE Fecha_Factura >= '20190501'
    AND LEFT(Codigo_departamento,2) IN ('F3','N1','N3','R1','R3','S1','T1','T3')
GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha_factura), MONTH(Fecha_factura)
ORDER BY YEAR(Fecha_factura) DESC, MONTH(Fecha_factura) DESC
```

Esto suponiendo que en la tabla fecha_cierre no haya fechas repetidas, sino duplicará los registros.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvio bastante tu respuesta. Yo asumia que un left join iba a alterar toda la consulta y por eso la descarte de plano, pero no es asi.

Comment: De nada @Oriel! Ma alegro que te haya sido util mi respuesta.